# How to select all letters in regex in Vala

Tags: regex, vala

I am using regexes in my function. And I need to wrap all my hashtags in string in  tags. But I can't figure out how to get all characters that are letters, [a-zA-Z] doesn't do exactly what I need, because people can use not English language and this regex won't work as expected.

Currently this is what I'm doing now, but this doesn't work as it should:

```
Regex hashtagRegex = new Regex("(#[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");
```

How can I do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\p{L}` to match any kind of letter from any language.

```
Regex hashtagRegex = new Regex("#([\\p{L}_]+)");
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but the compiler says "invalid escape sequence" and points at "\p"

Comment: yep, you need to escape \ one more time.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add second slash, I understoood. My mistake. Thanks for the answer)